# Use a trigger or advanced formula field?

Tags: trigger, force

I am new to Apex programming and salesforce. I just want to know if I want a field to have a lot conditions; should I do that in the advanced formula section or should I create a trigger. Basically, I want to calculate the commission, but the commission depends on how high or low the markup % is, so there will be a lot of conditions. Any answers will be greatly appreciated.

So this is what I have so far:

```
 IF(
   ISPICKVAL(Lead_Source__c , "Company Gen"),
     IF( Markup__c >=0 && Markup__c <=19, 0,
     IF( Markup__c >19 && Markup__c <=20, 0,
     IF( Markup__c >20 && Markup__c <=25, 0,
     IF( Markup__c >25 && Markup__c <=30, 0,
     IF( Markup__c >30 && Markup__c <=35, 3.00,
     IF( Markup__c >35 && Markup__c <=40, 4.50,
     IF( Markup__c >40 && Markup__c <=45, 4.50,
     IF( Markup__c >45 && Markup__c <=50, 6.50,
     IF( Markup__c >50 && Markup__c <=60, 7.50,
     IF( Markup__c >60 && Markup__c <=70, 8.00,
     IF( Markup__c >70 && Markup__c <=80, 8.50,
   Commission_Percentage__c)))))))))))),
IF(
   ISPICKVAL(Lead_Source__c , " Self-Gen"),
     IF( Markup__c >=0 && Markup__c <=19, 0,
     IF( Markup__c >19 && Markup__c <=20, 0,
     IF( Markup__c >20 && Markup__c <=25, 0,
     IF( Markup__c >25 && Markup__c <=30, 0,
     IF( Markup__c >30 && Markup__c <=35, 6.00,
     IF( Markup__c >35 && Markup__c <=40, 9.00,
     IF( Markup__c >40 && Markup__c <=45, 9.00,
     IF( Markup__c >45 && Markup__c <=50, 12.00,
     IF( Markup__c >50 && Markup__c <=60, 13.00,
     IF( Markup__c >60 && Markup__c <=70, 14.00,
     IF( Markup__c >70 && Markup__c <=80, 14.00,
   Commission_Percentage__c)))))))))))),
   Commission_Percentage__c)
```

The problem is that it gives me an error saying that there is any extra "," but when I take that out, then it says "extra IF". I don't know what to do, I need these conditions to be in a single field to calculate the commission percentage.

Comment: Just a note, you can just use the `<=` clauses, you don't need to define a range for each `IF`. Once you get past the first clause, you know that `>19` is true.

Comment: However, my code still is giving me an error I don't know why.

Comment: Remove `Commission_Percentage__c = ...` and just leave the `...` part. Is `Commission_Percentage__c` the name of the formula itself?

Comment: Yes, I am writing all the code for the Commission_Percentage__c field.  I still get an error. Essentially what I need to do for this commission percentage formula is to check whether the lead source is "Company Gen" or "Self-Gen", then it needs to check how much the markup % is, so I need a conditioned range (FOR EXAMPLE, markup >=0 and markup <=19 like i have above) depending on where the percent falls, then I want the commission percentage to be assigned a number not calculated. So do you think writing this code in a formula section is appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too much to put into a comment, but here are some notes:

- If you are writing a formula for the `Commission_Percentage__c` field, it should not contain any references to the field's own `API Name` (`Commission_Percentage__c`).
- If you are writing an `IF` clause, the syntax is `IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)`. You don't do any assignment, so no need to use any sort of `=` sign (unless you want to return an equality comparison, which is irrelevant here).
- You have many redundant range clauses. You can consolidate all ranges where `value_if_true` is the same.
- You have a leading space in your value for `" Self-Gen"`. It should probably be `"Self-Gen"`.
- Your fallback value if all of the ranges are false cannot be the formula itself. See the first bullet.
- If your `Markup__c` field is a percentage type, then you would compare `<= 35%` as `.35`. Remember to divide by 100.

---

Correct formula:

```
CASE(Lead_Source__c,
    "Company Gen",
        IF(Markup__c >= 0 && Markup__c <= .3, 0,
        IF(Markup__c <= .35, 3,
        IF(Markup__c <= .45, 4.5,
        IF(Markup__c <= .5, 6.5,
        IF(Markup__c <= .6, 7.5,
        IF(Markup__c <= .7, 8,
        IF(Markup__c <= .8, 8.5, null))))))),
    " Self-Gen",
        IF(Markup__c >= 0 && Markup__c <= .3, 0,
        IF(Markup__c <= .35, 6.00,
        IF(Markup__c <= .45, 9.00,
        IF(Markup__c <= .5, 12.00,
        IF(Markup__c <= .6, 13.00,
        IF(Markup__c <= .8, 14.00, null)))))),
    null
)
```

Comment: Alright I understand where what you're talking about. I shouldn't include the name of the API in the formula it self. However I just tried your formula and it gave an error: " Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'CASE()'. Expected 4, received 5"

Comment: Just wondering shouldn't you use ISPICKVAL because Lead_Source__c is a PICKLST?

Comment: Apparently you don't need to with the `CASE` function. That compile error was because I forgot the fallback if the `Lead_Source__c` is neither specified value. See updated formula. It really was expecting 6, not 4, but it can't really tell the difference. :)

Comment: So I have checked the syntax of your code, there are no errors, however the code also doesnt work because when i choose the "Company Gen" or "Self-Gen" from the lead source PickList none of the commission percentages come up. Actually nothing comes up for the commission percent. BTW I really appreciate the help. :p

Comment: Did you remove the leading space from `" Self-Gen"`? It works for me with `"Company Gen"`, although you may want to replace the `null` fallbacks with `0` instead.

Comment: Yes I removed the leading space from " Self-Gen", and I also replaced all the nulls with a 0. It doesnt give me any errors, but it does not work either. For example, I have the markup at 78% so it cant be 0%, but nothing shows when the markup % is at any number. Im just wondering why isn't the code that I have posted correct. Cause the only error I keep getting is about the ")"!!

Comment: It's a percentage? `78%` is actually `.78`. None of them are going to be `>1` (unless you go over `100%`).

Comment: Yes, the commission that is to be determined by the code you wrote needs to be a percentage.

Comment: If `Markup__c` is a percentage field, you need to divide all your comparison range values by 100. See my updated formula.

Comment: OMG it worked. Thanks alot man I really appreciate you helping me out!!! :)

Comment: Don't forget you can up-vote for useful answers once you hit 15 reputation, and can always accept an answer as correct if it solved your problem. @Alias311

Comment: Oh really thats good, how ever Im not at 15 yet. But I did give your answer a green checkmark!

Comment: Thanks again man! You did a great job and explained well!

Answer (score 1):

I'm in agreement with Anurag A, use out of the box whenever you can.  In addition, you may want to look into using **CASE** instead of the nested if's.  It makes the formula much easier to read and debug and you can use it with picklists :)

Comment: Alright let me give it a try.

Comment: You can't really do number ranges with `CASE`.

Comment: Yea thats what I eas thinking, I just tried it and it's not quite working out. I think my best way is to use the IF statements. But the code that i posted above is giving me syntax errors

Comment: Two possiblities:  use the case for the first choice (comp gen or self gen) with the nested ifs inside.  Also, do you need all the if statements before 30/35 %?  The true result for all of them is zero, right?  you would only need one statement (<=30 for the self-gen).  The length of the formula can become important, as there are limitations... and if you want to use this further in a formula, you will probably hit one.

Answer (score 0):

You should leverage the out of the box functionality wherever possible as it is the best practice. In you case, advanced formula section.

You can use various functions in the advance section formula to get it to work.

Custom code should be avoided wherever possible.

multiple if's can be used in formula.
 But sometimes you have to write triggers and code when the formulas doesn't work.

This is an example.

```
IF( 
  ISPICKVAL(object__r.relation_object__c.Type, "Subscription"), 
    IF( total__c > 9999, Regular_Total__c *0.30,
    IF( total__c> 500, Regular_Total__c *0.40,
    IF( total__c> 250, Regular_Total__c *0.50,
    IF( total__c > 100, Regular_Total__c *0.60,
    IF( total__c> 50, Regular_Total__c *0.70,
    IF( total__c> 25, Regular_Total__c *0.80,
    IF( total__c> 10, Regular_Total__c *0.90,
  Regular_Total__c)))))))),
IF( 
  ISPICKVAL(object__r.relation _object____c.Type, "Perpetual"),
    IF( total__c> 1000, Regular_Total__c *0.40,
    IF( total__c> 500, Regular_Total__c *0.50,
    IF( total__c> 250, Regular_Total__c *0.60,
  Regular_Total__c)))),
Regular_Total__c )
```

Comment: Alright but I will have many math conditions, how am I supposed to put that in the IF statement when it can only take 3 things in the parameters?

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: you can use multiple if's in formula

Comment: Really I tried using more than one and it kept giving me an error saying that there is an extra "IF". Maybe it's the way that the code is structured. I will try the way that you have done it.

Comment: Hey Anurag A, I have tried your method and this is what I am getting. Please check my post I edited it with my code.